# getting the mutex variable from strace

Tags: linux, pthreads, mutex, strace

I am using `strace` to get information about my application. I am interested in function for threading like the one below.

```
  futex(0xf70d34, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 23853, NULL <unfinished ...>
```

If I am not wrong this is used to lock a mutex.

Is there any way to retrieve which mutex in the code is the one that is locked from this information?

Comment: `0xf70d34` points to an integer that is used as your lock, the second is the operation (in this case WAIT, thus blocking the thread) and the third is a control value that is atomically compared to the value pointed by the first argument. so if you haven't implemented the mutex you're using yourself, i'm not sure you can find out which one it belongs to. perhaps there's a way to check the address space of the mutex, and perhaps try to compare the address of the first argument (in futex) to it, but i'm not sure.

Comment: as the previous comment noted you will need to have some way of associating the address listed by strace with the mutex variable.  In addition something to be aware of is that the futex operation will only show up in strace if there is lock contention.  Otherwise the operations is handled in user space without a system call.  I don't know what probably you are trying to solve, but you might be interested in looking at mutrace: http://git.0pointer.de/?p=mutrace.git